# Closed form for terms of two linked sequences, existence of limiting values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

Given:
$$
k_{r+1} = k_r \exp(-k_r\tau_r) \\
\tau_{r+1} = -\frac1{k_r}\ln\left(1-\frac{b}{k_r \sum_{i=0}^{r}\tau_i}\right) \\
$$
And that $k_0, \tau_0, b$ are constants, is there a closed form representation of $k_r, \tau_r, \forall r \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$? And can $\tau_0$ be represented in terms of $k_0$?

Edit: after calculating the sequence values computationally it appears that as $r\to\infty$, $k_r \to \infty, \tau_r\to\infty$, but the value of $e^{-k_r\tau_r} $ actually converges towards a limit. Why is this? Can this value be expressed in terms of $b, k_0, \tau_0$?

Comment: Do you know the Lambert's function ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Lambert's W function, plus I'm not sure I've been applying it correctly. The most I've managed is that $W(-k_{r+1} \tau_r) = -k_r \tau_r$, but this just seems to make things more complicated.

Comment: This is a nonlinear system of difference equations. Generally, there are no closed forms of solution for nonlinear systems of difference equations.